# What is this rounded, textured piece with connections at right angles?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Can someone please help me to identify this LEGO brick?

[image: rounded, textured piece zoomed-in]

Here is another view:

[image: rounded, textured piece in context]

Comment: I do not recognize this as a LEGO element.

Comment: Neither do I, where are these drawings from?

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that in official LEGO sets before, are you sure this instruction is not from a copycat company?

Comment: The style of the instructions doesn't look like LEGO's style of instructions to me.  As Henrik asked for, it would be great to know where these came from.

Comment: Maybe the "wagon wheel" element could be identified to find this set, and then look at the rest of the pieces in the set?

Comment: Only 2 wagon wheels have 10 spokes, the others have 8. Number of sets that have those wagon wheels is short enough for manual inspection in bricklink -> none of the sets having those wheels look remotely like the stuff in the photo. It's quite safe to assume this is not a Lego set...

Comment: This is a very popular brick in certain clone brands that specialise in military theme, but then it is in military green.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to prove a negative, but [searching Bricklink for "brick 1x1 modified"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=brick%201x1%20modified&rpp=100&tab=P#T=P) does not give any relevant results.

Combined with the utter lack of familiarity from all commenters above, it is more than probable that this is a 3rd party (clone) brick, and not an official LEGO design.